# Independent normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I found two theorems with a similar content and want to find out which one is true:

Let $X,Y$ be normally distributed random variables and

1. $X+Y$ is also normally distributed or
2. $ (X,Y)$ is bivariate normally distributed,

then $X,Y$ are independent iff they are uncorrelated.

I don't know whether $(1)$ or $(2)$ is the correct requirement, but maybe they are also equivalent?

Comment: The statement is correct if $(2)$ holds... not sure about the first one.

Comment: The (2) assumption is more common and implies (1). It is known that if ANY linear combination of X and Y is normal, then (X,Y) is bivariate normal. Whether "X,Y and X+Y normal" is sufficient, seems to be too hard for me.

Comment: this is more difficult than I anticipated. I have constructed a pair of random variables to show (1) does not imply (2). This still means it is not conclusive whether (1) $\rightarrow$ your statement.